# Appending rows in a specific column of a Pandas DF in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am pretty new to Pandas and I have a use-case like below:
I have a Dataframe like:

```
print (df)

         date    sector symbol   val1  val2
0  2000-01-31        IT      A  82.10  19.2
1  2000-01-31        IT     AA  28.00  20.3
2  2000-01-31    Sports     AB  32.22   1.2
3  2000-02-27  Industry      c  16.60   3.5
4  2000-02-27  Industry     cc  96.24   2.6
```

"date", "sector" and "symbol" are my key columns.
I want to group on "date" and rank the columns "val1" and "val2" in descending order and create a new dataframe with key columns and ranks for both (val1 and val2) instead of the actual values.

I'm using a for loop to iterate over the list of "date" and I use the pd.rank() function to find the rank. The problem here is that, I'm not able to properly Append rows to the new_df(the one with ranks). Below is my code:

```
    new_df = df.iloc[:,0:3] # This holds only key cols(date,sector,symbol)
    periods = np.sort(df['date'].dropna().unique())
    grped=df.groupby('date')
    for col in ['val1', 'val2']:
        new_df['{}_rnk'.format(col)] = "" #Creating a blank column for rank

        for dt in periods:
            t = pd.DataFrame()
            one = grped.get_group(dt)
            t = one[col].rank(ascending=flag,method='average')
            new_df['{}_rnk'.format(col)] = new_df['{}_rnk'.format(col)].append(t)
```

This is not giving me the right output. Can someone suggest what am I doing wrong or can tell a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe here is possible use [`GroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html) with [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and append to original `DataFrame` by [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
#set like need
flag=True
df1 = df.groupby('date')['val1', 'val2'].rank(ascending=flag,method='average')
df = df.join(df1.add_suffix('_rnk'))

print (df)
         date    sector symbol   val1  val2  val1_rnk  val2_rnk
0  2000-01-31        IT      A  82.10  19.2       3.0       2.0
1  2000-01-31        IT     AA  28.00  20.3       1.0       3.0
2  2000-01-31    Sports     AB  32.22   1.2       2.0       1.0
3  2000-02-27  Industry      c  16.60   3.5       1.0       2.0
4  2000-02-27  Industry     cc  96.24   2.6       2.0       1.0
```

Another solution with custom function with specified columns for descending and ascending rank:

```
mapp = pd.DataFrame({'column_name':['val1','val2'], 'direction':['Asc','Desc']})
print(mapp)
  column_name direction
0        val1       Asc
1        val2      Desc

asc_cols = [k for k, v in mapp.set_index('column_name')['direction'].items() if v == 'Asc']
desc_cols = [k for k, v in mapp.set_index('column_name')['direction'].items() if v == 'Desc']
print(asc_cols)
['val1']
print (desc_cols)
['val2']
```

Or:

```
asc_cols = []
desc_cols = []

for k, v in mapp.set_index('column_name')['direction'].items():
    if v == 'Desc':
        asc_cols.append(k)
    elif v == 'Asc':
        desc_cols.append(k)  

print(asc_cols)
print (desc_cols)

def func(x):
    x[asc_cols] = x[asc_cols].rank(ascending=True,method='average').add_suffix('_rnk')
    x[desc_cols] = x[desc_cols].rank(ascending=False,method='average').add_suffix('_rnk')
    return x

df1 = df.groupby('date')['val1', 'val2'].apply(func)
print (df1)
   val1  val2
0   3.0   2.0
1   1.0   1.0
2   2.0   3.0
3   1.0   1.0
4   2.0   2.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Here, you've taken the whole DF into memory. Actually, I have about 200 columns(val1, val2,...., val200) and around 5M rows. What if the pandas can't hold everything in memory? What should be done then?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Hard question, solution failed because out of memory?

Comment: No, it didn't as I am using a big machine. I was just a bit curious , hence I asked.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Added another solution, please check it if working better with your real data.

Comment: Actually, my use-case is a little vast. The "ascending" flag that is passed in the pd.rank(), can also vary for columns. Like, val1 needs to be ranked in asc order and val2 in desc order. This can happen for 200 columns in one DF. Hence, I was looking for one column ranking at a time. I am trying out your code for my use-case. If you can think of something else for the case I explained above, do share.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181075/discussion-between-mayank-porwal-and-jezrael).